# Load mask is not getting scrolled when page scrolled in extjs

Tags: extjs, scroll, loadmask

We have used load mask for a component (pie chart) in our application. when the page loads load mask is shown on that component. But, when the page is scrolled, the mask is not getting moved.

Can anyone help on this please?

Note: We are using ExtJS 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After using the property "useTargetEl:true", our problem is solved.

The final code for Load mask is:

var mask=Ext.create('Ext.LoadMask',{
    msg:'Please wait',
    target:cmpName,
    **useTargetEl**:**true**
});
mask.show();

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following approach:

```
// show the mask
me.down('#elementId').getEl().mask('Loading...');

// hide the mask
me.down('#timeline').getEl().unmask();
```